# How many of Ramanujan's discoveries have had a practical application?

Tags: soft-question, big-picture

I was reading about the Indian mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan who, before dying at the age of 32, independently compiled nearly 3900 results (this is from Wikipedia). So based on this he seems to have been a very prolific mathematician.

What I was curious about is how many of his results have had a practical application?

Comment: How many? 1729.

Comment: Why on Earth do people downvote this question? If you consider string theory to be practical, Ramanujan's discovery of mock theta functions is an excellent example. These were described in Ramanujan's last letter to Hardy and are currently appearing a lot in the physics literature.

Comment: If you stick to applications outside mathematics, another example that comes to mind is the appearance of the Rogers-Ramanujan identities in the hard hexagon model of statistical mechanics. I hope this question will be reopened so that people can elaborate.

Comment: A much more focused question about applications of some specific set of results to some specific other field would probably be fine.  As written, this question is horribly broad and sounds like it's more interested in factoids than actual math.

Answer (score 1):

At least one result have had a practical application.
Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function